# Add a column to function with fixed variable

Tags: r

I have this code as a function which generates the table of a Premier League season from Wiki.

```
read_prem_league <- function(year) { 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" %>%
  paste0(year - 1, "-", substr(as.character(year), 3, 4), "_Premier_League") %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(5)
}
```

`read_prem_league(2021)`

Who would create the following tibble:

```
#> # A tibble: 20 x 11
#>      Pos Team                   Pld     W     D     L    GF    GA GD      Pts
#>    <int> <chr>                <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int>
#>  1     1 Manchester City (C)     38    27     5     6    83    32 +51      86
#>  2     2 Manchester United       38    21    11     6    73    44 +29      74
#>  3     3 Liverpool               38    20     9     9    68    42 +26      69
#>  4     4 Chelsea                 38    19    10     9    58    36 +22      67
#>  5     5 Leicester City          38    20     6    12    68    50 +18      66
#>  6     6 West Ham United         38    19     8    11    62    47 +15      65
#>  7     7 Tottenham Hotspur       38    18     8    12    68    45 +23      62
#>  8     8 Arsenal                 38    18     7    13    55    39 +16      61
#>  9     9 Leeds United            38    18     5    15    62    54 +8       59
#> 10    10 Everton                 38    17     8    13    47    48 -1       59
#> 11    11 Aston Villa             38    16     7    15    55    46 +9       55
#> 12    12 Newcastle United        38    12     9    17    46    62 -16      45
#> 13    13 Wolverhampton Wande~    38    12     9    17    36    52 -16      45
#> 14    14 Crystal Palace          38    12     8    18    41    66 -25      44
#> 15    15 Southampton             38    12     7    19    47    68 -21      43
#> 16    16 Brighton & Hove Alb~    38     9    14    15    40    46 -6       41
#> 17    17 Burnley                 38    10     9    19    33    55 -22      39
#> 18    18 Fulham (R)              38     5    13    20    27    53 -26      28
#> 19    19 West Bromwich Albio~    38     5    11    22    35    76 -41      26
#> 20    20 Sheffield United (R)    38     7     2    29    20    63 -43      23
#> # ... with 1 more variable: `Qualification or relegation` <chr>
```

What I would like to do is to add a column called `Season` to the left of `Pos` which shows the current season, so it it's the season ending in 2020 I want it to to say 2019-20.

`read_prem_league$Season <- (year)`

The above code should work and I want to put it within the function. However, I get the error: `Error in View : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: The error in your post occured because you are using an incorrect syntax `read_prem_league` is a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

read_prem_league <- function(year) { 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" %>%
  paste0(year - 1, "-", substr(as.character(year), 3, 4), 
         "_Premier_League") %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(5) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Season = year, .before = Pos)
}
```

-testing

```
> dat <- read_prem_league(2021)
> dat
# A tibble: 20 × 12
   Season   Pos Team                       Pld     W     D     L    GF    GA GD      Pts `Qualification or relegation`                                     
    <dbl> <int> <chr>                    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <chr>                                                             
 1   2021     1 Manchester City (C)         38    27     5     6    83    32 +51      86 "Qualification for the Champions League group stage"              
 2   2021     2 Manchester United           38    21    11     6    73    44 +29      74 "Qualification for the Champions League group stage"              
 3   2021     3 Liverpool                   38    20     9     9    68    42 +26      69 "Qualification for the Champions League group stage"              
 4   2021     4 Chelsea                     38    19    10     9    58    36 +22      67 "Qualification for the Champions League group stage"              
 5   2021     5 Leicester City              38    20     6    12    68    50 +18      66 "Qualification for the Europa League group stage[a]"              
 6   2021     6 West Ham United             38    19     8    11    62    47 +15      65 "Qualification for the Europa League group stage[a]"              
 7   2021     7 Tottenham Hotspur           38    18     8    12    68    45 +23      62 "Qualification for the Europa Conference League play-off round[b]"
 8   2021     8 Arsenal                     38    18     7    13    55    39 +16      61 ""                                                                
 9   2021     9 Leeds United                38    18     5    15    62    54 +8       59 ""                                                                
10   2021    10 Everton                     38    17     8    13    47    48 −1       59 ""                                                                
11   2021    11 Aston Villa                 38    16     7    15    55    46 +9       55 ""                                                                
12   2021    12 Newcastle United            38    12     9    17    46    62 −16      45 ""                                                                
13   2021    13 Wolverhampton Wanderers     38    12     9    17    36    52 −16      45 ""                                                                
14   2021    14 Crystal Palace              38    12     8    18    41    66 −25      44 ""                                                                
15   2021    15 Southampton                 38    12     7    19    47    68 −21      43 ""                                                                
16   2021    16 Brighton & Hove Albion      38     9    14    15    40    46 −6       41 ""                                                                
17   2021    17 Burnley                     38    10     9    19    33    55 −22      39 ""                                                                
18   2021    18 Fulham (R)                  38     5    13    20    27    53 −26      28 "Relegation to the EFL Championship"                              
19   2021    19 West Bromwich Albion (R)    38     5    11    22    35    76 −41      26 "Relegation to the EFL Championship"                              
20   2021    20 Sheffield United (R)        38     7     2    29    20    63 −43      23 "Relegation to the EFL Championship"
```

Comment: When I put in the mutate code I get the following error: ```Error in View : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"```.

Comment: I tried the latest code with ```dplyr:mutate``` and gets the following: ```Error in UseMethod("mutate") :  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"```. Hmm...

Comment: @AnneSoled I used `packageVersion('rvest')
[1] ‘1.0.2’#
> packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.9’`

Comment: @AnneSoled that error is confusing as your own post says calling the `read_prem_league(2021)` returns the `tibble`

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Tried it in another chunk by mistake. I will check if it's works in a moment.